# How to save code doing it with OOP?

Tags: python, regex, oop

I'm writing a program to extract some data from txt files with regular expressions.

I'm new in OOP and want to save reiterative code. I want to retrieve about 15 data in each txt file, so I wrote a Class definition for each data.  The patters to match can come in several formats, so I'll need to try several regex patters.  By now, I only implements one regex patterns by data, but in future I need to try more in order to match the specific format used in that txt file, I plan to use a list with de patterns for each data.

I've just wrote 3 classes, but I've realized that I'm repeating too much code.  So, I believe that I'm doing something wrong.

```
import re
import os
import glob
import csv


class PropertyNumber(object):
    pattern_text = "(?<=FINCA Nº: )\w{3,6}"
    regex_pattern = re.compile(pattern_text)

    def __init__(self, str):
        self.text_to_search = str
        self.text_found = ""

    def search_p_number(self):
        matched_p_number = PropertyNumber.regex_pattern.search(self.text_to_search)
        print(matched_p_number)
        self.text_found = matched_p_number.group()
        return self.text_found


class PropertyCoefficient(object):
    pattern_text = "(?<=Participación: )[0-9,]{1,8}"
    regex_pattern = re.compile(pattern_text)

    def __init__(self, str):
        self.text_to_search = str
        self.text_found = ""

    def search_p_coefficient(self):
        matched_p_coefficient = PropertyCoefficient.regex_pattern.search(self.text_to_search)
        print(matched_p_coefficient)
        self.text_found = matched_p_coefficient.group()
        return self.text_found


class PropertyTaxIDNumber(object):
    pattern_text = "(?<=Referencia Catastral: )\d{7}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}[A-Z]\d{4}[A-Z]{2}"
    regex_pattern = re.compile(pattern_text)

    def __init__(self, str):
        self.text_to_search = str
        self.text_found = ""

    def search_tax_id(self):
        matched_p_taxidnumber = PropertyTaxIDNumber.regex_pattern.search(self.text_to_search)
        print(matched_p_taxidnumber)
        self.text_found = matched_p_taxidnumber.group()
        return self.text_found


def scan_txt_report(fli):
    data_retrieved = []
    file_input = open(fli, mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
    property_report = file_input.read()
    property_number = PropertyNumber(property_report)
    data_retrieved.append(property_number.search_p_number())
    property_coefficient = PropertyCoefficient(property_report)
    data_retrieved.append(property_coefficient.search_p_coefficient())
    property_tax_id_number = PropertyTaxIDNumber(property_report)
    data_retrieved.append(property_tax_id_number.search_tax_id())

    return data_retrieved


def main():
    if os.path.exists("./notas_simples/ns_txt"):
        os.chdir("./notas_simples/ns_txt")
        list_txt_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
        print(list_txt_files)
        with open("..\..\listado_de_fincas.csv", mode='w', newline='') as fiout:
            file_writer = csv.writer(fiout, delimiter=';')
            for file_name_input in list_txt_files:
                data_line = scan_txt_report(file_name_input)
                file_writer.writerow(data_line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# TODO Idufir: "(?<=IDUFIR: )\d{14}"
# TODO calle: "(?<=Calle ).*"   Break down in street name and number of address
# TODO piso: "(?<=piso ).*,"    Break down in floor number and door number (or letter), without boundaries
# TODO titularidad: "(?<=TITULARIDAD\n\n).*"    Break down in owner name, VAT number, % and domai type.
```

As you can see above, the 3 classes I've already wrote: PropertyNumber(object), PropertyCoefficient(object) and PropertyTaxIDNumber(object), has a lot of repeated code.  Thus, when I add some regex patterns to each class will be worse.

Comment: Are you adamant on using OOP for this? It's really quite overkill for what you're doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are repeating much of your code, and yes, it is a sign of a weak design. I'll take this as an OOP exercise, because this is an overkill.

First, we can see that the only difference between the different classes is their essence, and their regex pattern. So we can have a base class which handles all the repetitive code. Now each subclass simply handles the different pattern:

```
class BaseProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, search_str, pattern):
        self.text_to_search = search_str
        self.text_found = ""
        self.regex_pattern = re.compile(pattern)

    def search_property(self):
        matched_property = self.regex_pattern.search(self.text_to_search)
        print(matched_property)
        self.text_found = matched_property.group()
        return self.text_found

class PropertyNumber(BaseProperty):
    def __init__(self, search_str):
        super(PropertyNumber, self).__init__(search_str, "(?<=FINCA Nº: )\w{3,6}")

class PropertyCoefficient(BaseProperty):
    def __init__(self, search_str):
        super(PropertyCoefficient, self).__init__(search_str, "(?<=Participación: )[0-9,]{1,8}")
```

Second, it doesn't appear that you're actually using the `self.text_found` field, so why store it? Now you can init all the properties in a single place, and make your `scan_txt_report` much simpler.

```
class BaseProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.regex_pattern = re.compile(pattern)

    def search_property(self, search_str):
        matched_property = self.regex_pattern.search(search_str)
        print(matched_property)
        return matched_property.group()
```

...

```
class PropertyCoefficient(BaseProperty):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PropertyCoefficient, self).__init__("(?<=Participación: )[0-9,]{1,8}")

properties = [PropertyNumber(), PropertyCoefficient(), ...]

def scan_txt_report(fli):
    file_input = open(fli, mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
    property_report = file_input.read()
    data_retrieved = [prop.search_property(property_report) for prop in properties]
    return data_retrieved
```

And unless you add some specific functionality for each subclass, you can even let go of the specific properties classes, and just do like this:

```
properties = [BaseProperty("(?<=FINCA Nº: )\w{3,6}"), BaseProperty("(?<=Participación: )[0-9,]{1,8}")]
```

And one last thing - please see the comment by @JonClements - it's a bad idea to use reserved words (such as `str`) as variable names.

Comment: Might be an idea to rename your `str`s to `text` (or similar) - as the OP appears new, it's probably best not to offer example code that shadows builtins (even though in this case it doesn't really matter).

Comment: @Korem thaks.  As you can see in my todos some data will be need to break down into more detailed data, so I'll need the `self.text_found` and add specific functionality for these classes (which will returns tuples of data instead a single string).  As both of you suggest me, I've already renamed `str` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for so many classes.It can be done via two classes.

```
Class Property(object,regex):
     #def __init__ ...
     #def prepare (This method will prepare return compiled form of regex


Class Search(object,compiled_regex):
    #def __init__ ...
    #def search ... (same function as now)


def scan_txt_report(fli):
    data_retrieved = []
    file_input = open(fli, mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
    #take a csv containing all the regex.
    #for all regex call property and search classes.keep appending results as well.

return data_retrieved
```

This way the only thing we need to change is the csv.The program remains intact and tested.
For adding new regex's the csv needs to be updated.